# New Admin theme in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, admin-panel

I need to install new admin theme for my magento admin panel.

1. Can anyone suggest free admin theme to me.

   Then if I install that admin theme, What kind of issues I will face in js related.? 

   and

   Installing admin theme is a good idea or bad one.?

Comment: Although there are many such admin themes available for Magento 1.x, almost all of those only change some normal styling and colors etc.

Comment: Can you suggest any best admin theme or themes' website?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to keep default admin theme.

Installing admin theme may sometimes result in issues and it is waste of time to spend on it.

Answer (score 0):

As Mohit stated, most themes are just a style and color change. I prefer to use this one as it makes the buttons larger, color coordinated, and gives some customization about the styles being changed

https://www.vnecoms.com/free-magento-extensions/v-admin.html